# Connection ASP.NET Core to MySQL without EF, but with dependency injection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying out asp.net out and I'm having issues doing the simplest thing, connecting to a database. I have no clue how to call my context via dependency injection to use in my repository, if anyone can help me out it would be great. Here is my code:

Model:

```
 public class User
{
   ...attrs...
}
```

Interface / Repo:

```
public interface UserRepository
{
    List<User> GetUsers();
}

public class UserRepositoryImpl : UserRepository
{
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        //I NEED THE CONTEXT FOR "db" HERE!
        using (MySqlConnection con = db.GetConnection())
        {
            List<User> list = new List<User>();
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user", con);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(new User()
                    {
                        ...read stuff...
                    });
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

My Context:

```
public class MyContext
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public MyContext(string connectionString)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Service registration:

```
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(MyContext), new MyContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));
```

Most tutorials either force me to use EF and others don't do the dependency injection, if anyone could guide me or point me to the right direction I would be really greatful! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I got it to work using this in my controller after creating a constructor that takes in the context for my db:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/user")]
public class UserController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public List<User> AllUsers()
    {
        MyContext db = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyContext)) as MyContext;
        UserRepositoryImpl repo = new UserRepositoryImpl(db);
        return repo.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

I still believe this can be improved though, is there a better way to do this? Thanks

**EDIT2:** Finally got it to work using this controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/user")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    MyContext db;
    public UserController(MyContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<User> AllUsers()
    {
        UserRepository repo = new UserRepository(db);
        return repo.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

Thanks to Tseng's answer!

Comment: Would you please add the code you mentioned without dependancy injection that works (without ef)?

Comment: I don't have one actually, I just went straight into doing this with my connection string in my json. I did try it out before without it and it worked, the other way it worked was by not using a repo and just putting the methods in my context class and using the GetConnection method from it as a private method

Comment: `MyContext` should be interfaced for the best scenario when having to plug in new db support, but in the current case all you should have to do is add a constructor to the `UserRepositoryImpl` class that takes a parameter of type `MyContext` (save this instance to a private readonly field).  Then use that instance for db calls.

Comment: Where do I get the context from in my controller then? I still need to get the dependency somehow and calling MyContext db; in the controller just references to a null object like in my repo

Comment: Dependency Injection is same for everything, no matter if its a context, or any other service class. You configure it in the startup (using `services.AddXxx<X,Y>()` and injecting it in the constructor. And btw., unlike in Java-world, we use "I" to prefix interfaces and don't surfix the implementations with "Impl" :)

Comment: Woops haha guess it shows where I'm coming from, thanks Tseng I'll try it out again in a bit